# Get height for dynamic update DIV on mootools 1.2.5

Tags: html, height, mootools1.2

```
<div id="igpopup">
    <div id="igbottom"></div>
    </div>
```

I use mootools 1.2.5.
In "igbottom" add content over ajax.
Before add contet div "igpopup" have height = 200px.
Apter add content height = 200px :(.
Overflow not use.
Can get height div "igpopup" after add content in div "igbottom"?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the exact question. 
Height after a dynamic change to a div tag can be found in mootools by using:

```
    var height = $('divId').offsetHeight;
```

if the div is closed, or hidden but you want it's open height, consider flipping the div open, measuring the height, and then closing the div again.  This all happens without onscreen document (visible) changes. If you need directions lookup "How to calculate each element's height and use these values as a variable in function?".  There is a mootools answer in there.